# Combine named range with other options in one data validation list

Tags: excel, validation, named-ranges

I have a named range in Excel that contains user-entered manufacturers of cars.  I want to use this named range in another table as a data validation dropdown list, but also include two other options: blank and "Manufacturer not in list".  Is there a way to do this without including these two other options in the user-entered car manufacturer list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to combine two range names into a new range (using the name formula `=RangeOne,Range2` ), that results in a multi-area range which cannot be used in data validation.

For a DV list you will need to construct a new, contiguous range in the grid and reference that for DV. That can be done with a variety of techniques, i.e. formulas, VBA or Power Query.